# proving function of a Cauchy sequence is Cauchy

Tags: sequences-and-series

Given {x$_n$} is a Cauchy sequence in $\mathbb Q$. To show that {a$^{x_n}$} (a>0,a$\in \mathbb R$) is Cauchy. I tried to prove it by using the theorem "A function f:S $\rightarrow$ $\mathbb R$ is uniformly continuous iff f takes a Cauchy sequence to a Cauchy sequence". But then I understood that the map x $\rightarrow$ a$^x$ is not uniformly continuous in an unbounded subset of $\mathbb R$ and also I've missed to note that in the theorem I mentioned above S must be a bounded subset of $\mathbb R$.So I cannot use it here...I then tried with the definition of Cauchy,but I couldn't do it...plz help me

Answer (score 2):

Any Cauchy sequence is bounded. Use that to work over a bounded domain.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the continuity of the map $x\rightarrow a^x$ in the rationals. Take $\epsilon>0$ then there exists a $\delta>0$ such that $|x_n-x_m|<\delta$ implies $|a^{x_n}-a^{x_m}|<\epsilon$. Since $x_n$ is cauchy, the hypothesis can be guarantied to be true for all $n, m$ beyond some threshold $N$, this is, $n,m\geq N$. This completes the proof since we have have found a threshold for which $n,m\geq N$ implies $|a^{x_n}-a^{x_m}|<\epsilon$.